# Select a table using mouse in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Normally I can select a table by placing the mouse cursor at the upper left corner. And the cursor changes shape to imply we can select the table by a click.

On one particular workbook this doesn't work;

- The cursor just doesn't change shape. I can't select the table this way.
- Also, can't select rows/columns by clicking top / left sides.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for column selection works.
- The document was an `.xls` file and I upgraded it by saving it as an `.xlsx`, no change.
- The document doesn't have macros or locked cells.
- It works on other documents.
- It works if I create a new table on a new sheet. No new tables will work on the existing sheet.

I've experienced this a few times in the past, but don't remember how resolved it, or I just didn't need to resolve.

Sample file : http://sdrv.ms/12xb2dy

Comment: What do you mean by "document"? And how is a "document" different from a file where the table selection works? Can you post a sample "document" that shows the behaviour you describe?

Comment: @teylyn By 'document' I mean a file. It was a simple older (xls) format file with a sheet of data. I converted it to a table and saved it in the newer 'xlsx' format. I can't post as it contains private data. I will try to create a sample though.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of how a table is selected by clicking the upper left corner? In what software?

Comment: @teylyn I've edited the question to include a sample file. In the sample file, I can't select the table and its rows / columns using the way I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

> Normally I can select a table by placing the mouse cursor at the upper left corner. And the cursor changes shape to imply we can select the table by a click.

This sounds more like a Word table than an Excel workbook. When hovering over a table, Word shows a little square at the top left corner of a table that can be used to select the table.

Excel does not have such a thing.

In Excel 2003 tables don't exist. You can format a range as a list. If you hover over the top left corner of the top left cell, there will be a couple of pixels where the mouse changes to an arrow that points SouthEast. If you are lucky enough to catch this state and click, the list will be selected, including the headers.

In Excel 2007 and later, you can create a table instead of a list. Again, there is a tiny area near the  top left cell of the table that shows the South-East pointing arrow. If you are lucky enough to manage to click while it shows, the table **content** will be selected, but not the table headers.

[Edit]
As far as I know there is no way to select a whole Excel table with a single mouse click. Even the F5/Goto > TableName will only select the table contents, without the headers

The shortest way to select a table WITH headers in Excel 2007 and above is to click the top left cell and do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>down arrow</kbd>-<kbd>right arrow</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for the information. Yes, the South-East pointing arrow is what I mean by the cursor changing its shape to imply we can click to select the table =)

Comment: OK. So Excel 2007 and higher still has that functionality, but the selection does not include the column headers. I've edited my answer above to include a keyboard shortcut as an alternative.

Comment: In terms of a keyboard shortcut, click into any cell in the header row and `Ctrl-A` will select the whole table. If you click into the table to do this then the selection will not include the header row.

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of the keyboard shortcuts, but trying to solve what makes this problem and how to resolve it.

Comment: I see the same behaviour. I assume it has to do with the fact that the workbook was converted from a previous Excel version. Case in point is that it works fine on a new sheet. You can copy the table, then paste with values only to a new sheet, then turn it into a table again.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean and there is a "trick" for getting the southeast arrow on a table. I have had a lot of trouble with this.

Select a cell that is outside the table, then just gently slide (no clicking) up towards the "select all" cell, but don't go into it.
You will see the southeast arrow when you are just to the right of that "select all" cell.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem.
It seems you loose the selection arrows in Excel tables when you protect the sheet.
And they don't come back if you unprotect the sheet.
It took me a while to figure it out.

You can get the arrows back by unlocking the header cells of the table (right click, format cells, Protection tab, untick Locked box).
Once the header cells are unlocked, you will always get the selection arrows, whether the sheet is protected or not.

Hope this helps.

Marc.